# invalid option: --output-style

Tags: ruby, sass, gulp, gulp-sass, generator-gulp-angular

Hi i'm facing `outptStyle` error in **sass** i am using **generator-gulp-angular**

`gulp-ruby-sass: stderr: OptionParser::InvalidOption: invalid option: --output-style Use --trace for backtrace`

i saw backtrace sass documentation but didn't work in this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after an hour of googling finally i found the solution.

`Change line 25 in gulp/styles.js from outputStyle: 'expanded', to style: 'expanded'`

[github issue](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular/issues/1160)